# Firebase Database Security Rules - Allow access to friends

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to give read access to posts made by a user based on the user being a friend of the author. However, Firebase tells me "variable unknown $friendId". Here are my

```
rules:

users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
          "posts": {
            "public": {
              ".read" : "auth != null"
            },
              "private" : {
                ".read": "root.child('users').child($uid).child('friends').child($friendId) === auth.id"
              }
          }
      }
```

Basically, I want Firebase to check if /users/$uid/friends/ contains the friends Id and give permission to read /users/$uid/posts/private if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Firebase seems to be unable to accept new variables from the condition statement. However, you can just use `auth.variables`. All I did was change the final part about the private posts:

```
"private": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child($uid).child('friends').child(auth.uid).exists()"
}
```